# how to create a debian package which updates only required files while updating the package

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, debian, packaging

After few weeks of struggle i am able to create a medium native package debian package which works well in installation and removing of the package.

As http://www.quietsche-entchen.de/cgi-bin/wiki.cgi/-wiki/CreatingDebianPackages
Debian wiki
http://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/ these are the quite good material for beginners,

I have basic problem, in updating the package all the files data.tar.gz are updated by default.

I want only few files to get updated in the data.tar.gz based on a key variable stored in all the files.

After the unpacking that is executing preinst script, all the files in data.tar.gz are already updated..

my idea was to take back up of the files intially before upgrading the package, and check key variable in files.. if the key variable is greater than the current variable replace it..

which means i am writing a simple backup script.. and executing in the postinst file..

i donot think this is good idea.. and more over limitations in dash script make it a very tough job..

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish here? During the reinstallation (or upgrading) of a Debian package, replacement of all of the non-conffiles with the latest version is exactly what's *supposed* to happen. If the file hasn't changed since the last installed version of the package then there's no harm in updating it anyway, and if is *has* changed, it's supposed to be updated.

If you have specific files which might be modified by the user and should be preserved across upgrades, make then conf files. The package system will prompt the user and ask them if they want to keep the package maintainer's version or the locally modified version.

(But if you're going to make every file a conf file, then you're probably doing something wrong.)

To make a file a conffile, list it in `debian/conffiles`. But if the file is going to be installed under `/etc` then you don't need to do this because `dh_installdeb` will do it for you.

**EDIT** following additional information in comment:

Suppose you have files `test1.sh` and `test2.sh` (among others) in your package. In the Debian world, they are either conffiles are intended to be modified by the end user, or they're not.

conffiles should be relatively few in number and as short as possible, to minimize the burden of having to reconcile changes made by the package maintainer with conflicting changes made by the end user.

If there are things mixed into the code that the end user is likely to want to tune, try to factor them out into a configuration file. If you put that file in `/etc`, you don't even have to manually designate it as a conffile.

If the end user needs to make a change to a non-conffile, they should use the [dpkg-divert](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/118) protocol to (1) move the original file aside, and (2) edit a copy. Diverted files are respected by package upgrades. The end user who uses `dpkg-divert` should be aware that things might break after upgrades as a result, because the package maintainer hasn't foreseen that these files would be modified by end users and the locally modified version might be incompatible with a newly upgraded version of a different file. `dpkg-divert` should be used carefully and sparingly.

Comment: I will try to explain what i want to achieve in simple examples. lets say i have two files in data.tar.gz say test1.sh, test2.sh and my debain package version is 2.0, I have updated the test2 in file in the system, and i have created new debian package with 2.1 version with some changes in test1.sh. If i have updated my package two files would be updated, which i donot want , i just want test1.sh to be updated, The above explanation would work if I have only few files, buis there any other possibility if my package consists of more than 100 files unless than creating the con files..

Comment: @Celeda just know i have seen another post regarding dpkg-divert but this is will not work in my scenario , where end user would never use dpkg-divert in order to change the file.... is there is any other possibility to control the deletion of the all the previous version files and installing the new version on "postrm upgrade" and "posinst configure" calls in this diagram http://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts or any other way to control the default behavior of installation any how thanks for your time and support

Comment: Please explain "where end user would never use dpkg-divert in order to change the file". Why would they not use `dpkg-divert` to change a non-conffile? Using `dpkg-divert` is exactly what they're supposed to use.

Comment: thanks for your help and time... i have solved this problem by taking backup of the files before upgrading it new version....end user will not use dpkg-divert because i donot want them to use to maintain consistency in various systems.....